# AWS Directory Services not resolving resources within VPC with Private IP address

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-vpc

I set up an Microsoft AD using Directory services inside of an existing VPC, and now all DNS requests inside of the VPC resolve to the public IP of the instances.  For example, an RDS instance now will return the Public IP instead of the private one.

This is preventing me from properly setting up my Security groups, and is generally making my DNS wonky. DNS requests to Route 53 assets hosted within the VPC also fail, but work from outside the VPC.

I contacted support and was told

> The reason you are getting the public IP address is because the domain name servers that are specified are doing the resolution themselves. When this happens, they get the external IP of the RDS instance because the query is not going through the VPC resolver.
>
> In order for you to get the private IP address returned, you will need to setup your AD DNS to forward queries to the local VPC resolver. You would need to log into the AD machine to do so.
>
> For your reference, the VPC resolver always sits at the +2 address. That means since your VPC is 172.30.0.0/16, the DNS resolver will be at 172.30.0.2.

Is this possible using Directory Services?  What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Private VPC DNS addresses are known within the VPC. You can also create a private hosted zone in Route53. Each VPC has a DNS resolver that knows where to go to translate DNS entries.

Active Directory uses its own DNS server to resolve addresses. What AWS suggested is to setup your Active Directory server's DNS server to know about the VPC resolver. You can either setup the DNS server to forward all requests to the VPC resolver or just ones that match a particular zone.

Comment: How do you set Directory Services to forward all DNS requests to the VPC resolver?

Comment: http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/sln164002/how-to-create-a-conditional-forwarder-on-a-windows-dns-server?lang=en

Comment: Make sure that you understand what you are changing. AD is very dependent on DNS being setup correctly. Backup the system before implementing any changes (e.g. create an AMI to recover from).